# How to get all Site Collections using C# CSOM

Tags: c#, csom, sitecollection

My Code:

```
                SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = null;
                Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
                int startIndex = 0;

                while (spp == null || spp.Count > 0)
                {
                    spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(startIndex, true);
                    clientContext.Load(spp);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<br/> All Sites Collection: " + sp.Title + "<br/>");
                       // siteCols.Add(new SiteCol(sp.Title, sp.Url));

                      //  startIndex = siteCols.Count;
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                }
```

I am getting this Error : Method Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load: type argument 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T

Is there any other way to retrieve all site collections?

Comment: I tried clientContext.Web.Webs, but I am getting subSites names. I want site collections title.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> Method Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load: type
>   argument
>   'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

occurs since there is mismatch between `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly and the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` assembly versions that are referenced in project.

Microsoft released the following SDKs:

- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038): `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly version **16** (`C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\16.0\Assemblies`) is shipped with this SDK
- [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585): `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly version **15** (`C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\Assemblies`) is shipped with this SDK

**Resolution**

Ensure the proper version of `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly is referenced.

For example, for SharePoint Online project the the following assembly should be referenced: `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c`

Answer (score 0):

type([see](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Sharepoint.2013.Client.16/)):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Sharepoint.2013.Client.16
```